# Vue cookie sets as an object from seperate js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I run into a problem here somehow my cookies is set as an `object object` it should instead set like `token`. I'm setting it from seperate `js` file.

So this is the `js` files which holds the function to set cookie:

```
export const authenticate = (username, password) => {
    API.post('/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.token)
        if(response.data.token) {
            Vue.cookie.set({'token': response.data.token});
            router.push({name: 'home'});
        } else {
            const error = 'Something went wrong. Try again.';
            return console.log({'error': error});
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        //error = 'Something went wrong. Try again.';
        return console.log(error);
    });    
}
```

`console.log(response.data.token)` this logs me plain text token.

and then in `Login.vue` I call this function:

```
methods: {
    authenticateUser() {
        authenticate(this.username, this.password);
    }
}
```

And cookie sets like this: [object Object]

Comment: What library are you using to handle cookies? All google searches show `set()` should be used like `.set('token', response.data.token)` rather than with an object `{}`.

Comment: What shows up when you log `response.data.token`?

Comment: @Lewis maybe you should post as an answer so that, the question will not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Lewis answer in the comments worked! I used wrong syntax.

Instead of `Vue.cookie.set({'token': response.data.token});`

Need to use: `Vue.cookie.set('token', response.data.token);`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of library that you used to handle cookie seems strange.

You can try [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to handle it like below,

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
Cookies.set('token', response.data.token)
```